# iOS: How to Recognize that We Got Back from a Child UIViewController within the Parent UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

Let's say that I have 2 UIViewControllers on a stack within a UINavigationController. In the "parent" we call "[self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];" upon some user action and in the "child" we call "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];" upon some user action.

How can we recognize within the parent that we just got back?

Is there some "event" driven method that can recognize that this popViewControllerAnimated action was called from the child?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you're using this child controller as a modal in that it can be 'dismissed'. If that is the case, try to follow Apple's patterns that they use for UIAlertViews.

If that is the case, I'd do either of the following to implement a delegate pattern(delegate vs block is a huge debate that I will not get into here) so the owner(the one that pushes the child on) knows when its dismissed:

- Create a protocol (ChildControllerDelegate), have one method in it childControllerWasDismissed:(ChildController *)
- add a block property(make sure its a copy property, not retain) to the ChildController

You'll then want to call the delegate method or block on viewDidDisappear.  If you want finer grain control, have a delegate method or block that corresponds viewWillDisappear / viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 4):

I'd successfully resolved this by setting `navigationController?.delegate = self` and then implementing this method to determine whether the current view controller is shown again after a pop.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            // we got back
        } else {
            // some other controller was pushed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few way to hint at that. What you can do, is call the popViewControllerAnimated from the parent. You can do that by passing a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) to the child controller that would then execute the said block and thus popping would be done by the parent controller.

You can also use the UINavigationController delegate to be notified when a UIViewController will be dismissed:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

This method will let you know which VC will be shown and you can check if the current (not yet popped) VC is the child you were looking for.

You can also do some trick with - (void)viewWillAppear: but this might require some hacks.

Answer (score 0):

First read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457), it will help you understand what is going on with view controllers.

Then implement `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` in your parent view controller to log a message.

Comment: This does not tell you, however, which other controller has been popped. There may exist several different ones. But not at a time in a pushed state, of course, so the OP can simply keep track of which controller was pushed last.